# Django Models: Time not Date?

Tags: django, django-models

I know models.DateField(), but I want to be able to just add a 24 hour time that is independent of a date. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [TimeField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield).